# Regex shortest possible match

Tags: javascript, regex

Given:

```
A 1234 AAAAAA AAAAAA 1234 7th XXXXX Rd XXXXXX
```

I want to match:

```
1234 7th XXXXX Rd
```

Using nothing more than `Rd` and `\d+`
so i tried: `\d+.*?Rd`

but it matches starting from the first 1234 up to Rd instead of the  second 1234, i thought `.*?` would match the shortest possible match, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show an example input which better illustrates the problem?  Both of the answers already given below get your intended result in this particular case.  But what do you mean by "shortest" possible match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using more than `Rd` and `\d+` when you add `.*` which will match anything. If you can assume `NUMBER-SPACE-SOMETHING-Rd` as the format - then you could add `\s` to the mix and use

```
/(\d+\s+\d+.*?Rd)/
```

```js
console.log('A 1234 AAAAAA AAAAAA 1234 7th XXXXX Rd XXXXXX'.match(/(\d+\s+\d+.*?Rd)/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern:

```
^.*(1234 7th.*?Rd).*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^.*        from the start of the greedily consume everything until
(1234 7th  capture from the last occurrence of 1234 7th
.*?Rd)     then non greedily consume everything until the first Rd
.*$        consume, but don't capture, the remainder of the string
```

Here is a code snippet:

```js
var input = "A 1234 AAAAAA AAAAAA 1234 7th XXXXX Rd XXXXXX";
var regex = /^.*(1234 7th.*?Rd).*$/g;
var match = regex.exec(input);
console.log(match[1]); // 1234 7th XXXXX Rd
```